# XAML Data Binding: Unexpected results when setting class property from within DispatcherTimer's tick event

Tags: c#, xaml, binding

Hello to everyone who may visit this topic.  I am attempting to understand the basic principles of XAML data binding.  As you can see, here's a simple Universal Windows Program.

**BACKGROUND:**  The bound element on MainPage.xaml **WILL NOT** receive data from the DataContext (ClockDispatcher.cs) if code placement (A) ***desired location*** is executed within the class.

The bound element on MainPage.xaml **WILL** eceive data from the DataContext (ClockDispatcher.cs) if code placement (B) ***testing general binding only*** is executed within the class.

When Debugging either CODE PLACEMENT OPTION, the locals windows shows that the public property "MyClock.Time" **IS** being set.  But the bound element on MainPage.xaml is only realized when CODE PLACEMENT (B) ***testing general binding only*** is executed.

**QUESTION:**  Is there an error in my logic that would prohibit the ability to set a class property as shown AND have that result be delivered to the associated bound element?  Please be aware that the class property assignment takes place within the ***dispatcherTimer_Tick*** method.

**Thank you** in advance, for taking the time and effort to help me understand this issue!

Best Regards,
DMMcCollum

**MainPage.xaml**

```
    <Page
x:Class="TestBinding.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TestBinding"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:data="using:TestBinding.Models"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.DataContext>
    <data:ClockDispatcher />
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock x:Name="TimeTextBlock" Text="{Binding MyClock.Time, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**ClockDispatcher.cs**

```
    namespace TestBinding.Models
{
public class ClockDispatcher
    {
    //Bound to "TimeTextBlock" on MainPage.xaml
    public Models.Clock MyClock { get; private set; } = new Models.Clock();

    public ClockDispatcher() 
        {
        //CODE PLACEMENT (B)
        //If executed here - WILL set class public property and WILL BE reflected in UI (but not updated as understood) 
        //MyClock.Time = string.Format("{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("t"));

        DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;

        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
        }



    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
        //CODE PLACEMENT (A)
        //if executed here - WILL set class public property and WILL NOT BE reflected in UI (but updates property on each tick interval as understood)
        MyClock.Time = string.Format("{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("t"));
        }
    }
}
```

**Clock.cs**

```
    namespace TestBinding.Models
{
public class Clock
    {
    public string Time { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement INotifyPropertyChanged in class Clock so that any change in source or target are in-sync.

**Why it is working in Code Placement B -** Since, the property value is set in constructor before Initialling the controls so value will always be set at load.

**Why it is working in Code Placement A -** - It is in different function which is called after the load of window.

**Fix** 
    public class Clock: INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
           private string time;

```
       public string Time 
       {

           get 
            {
               return this.time;
            }
            set
            {
               this.time = value;
               NotifyPropertyChanged("Time");
            }
         }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you so very much for the code example. Together with your example and the input from @kirotab, I was able to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

You need to notify the **View** for the change in your **View Model**, that is done with the help of `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface (There is a lot of information how to implement it) or using some of the MVVM frameworks like: **MVVM Light**, **Prism**, etc ...

[INotifyPropertyChanged Interface MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) The example is given in `Win Forms` project but essentially it's the same as `WPF`.

You're able to set the values to the control directly but bindings will not work this way.

For collections of data you could use something like `ObservableCollection` which notifies the view for changes in it's elements, eg you don't have to call Raise PropertyChanged event when you add an item, the collection will know that there is new item inserted.

Comment: I really appreciate your response.  It helped point me in the right direction to solution my issue.